# Existence of a Lyapunov function for $-h'\varphi'+\varphi''$ where $h\in C^1(\mathbb R)$ such that $h'$ is Lipschitz

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-differential-equations, stability

Let $h\in C^1(\mathbb R)$ such that $h'$ is Lipschitz continuous and $$L\varphi:=-h'\varphi'+\varphi''\;\;\;\text{for }\varphi\in C^2(\mathbb R).$$ The formal adjoint of $L$ is $$L^\ast\psi:=\psi''+(h'\psi)'\;\;\;\text{for }\psi'\in C^2(\mathbb R).$$ Note that $L^\ast e^{-h}=0$.

> Are we able to show that there is a Borel measurable (hopefully continuous) function $v:\mathbb R\to[0,\infty)$ such that $$Lv\le c-\lambda v\tag1$$ for some $c\ge0$ and $\lambda>0$?

Comment: One needs more assumptions on $h$, e.g., a dissipativity condition is sufficient.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Can you provide details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $h'(x)$ satisfies a *dissipativity condition*: there exists $K>0$ and $A \ge 0$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $x h'(x) \ge K x^2 - A$.  Consider as a candidate function $v(x) = x^2$.  Then, $$
L v(x) = - x h'(x) + 1 \le - K x^2 + A + 1 \;.
$$ So, (1) is satisfied with $\lambda=K$ and $c=A+1$.

Other conditions are possible.  See, e.g., Assumption 2.1 (B) and Lemma 2.5 of [Non-Asymptotic Mixing of the MALA Algorithm](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1008.3514.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This question arose in me while I've tried to find a solution for [an other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3057994/convergence-of-the-distribution-of-the-langevin-diffusion-to-its-invariant-measu). Is this the right track or is there an easier solution available which doesn't need furhter assumptions on $h$?

Comment: Adding further assumptions is the right track. Otherwise you could be in a situation where $e^{-h}$ might not be integrable or the infinitesimally invariant measure with density $e^{-h}$ might not be an invariant measure for the process.

Comment: Actually, in the application I've got in mind $h=-\ln f$ for some positive $f\in C^2(\mathbb R)$ such that $f'/f$ is Lipschitz and $\lambda f=1$. Does that change the situation?

Comment: What do you mean by $\lambda f = 1$?

Comment: $\lambda$ being the Lebegue measure, $\lambda f:=\int f\:{\rm d}\lambda$.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't change the situation, because a Lipschitz drift is insufficient.  As a counterexample, think about $f$ being heavy-tailed.  You can read a lot more about this in the following nice paper by Roberts and Tweedie https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e86f/414f860a1a70e16d9718c887f4eb59a51f62.pdf  The authors make the point that the one-dimensional Langevin diffusion is exponentially ergodic if and only if the tails of $f$ are no heavier than exponential.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Just one more thing: We are interested in the existence of a Lyapunov function, since it ensures that a Poincaré inequality ($(9)$ in the other question) is satisfied, right? Is it easy to prove that $(9)$ holds, when $v$ exists?

Comment: The main interest in a Lyapunov function is to conclude that eventually most of the mass of the transition probabilities of the Langevin diffusion, and in turn, the measure with density $e^{-h}$ are confined to a compact set.  This is the viewpoint taken in the papers I referenced.

Comment: But does the existence allow to conclude $(9)$? If not, what's the easiest approach to conclude that the distribution of $X_t$ (in the other question) converges to the invariant measure $\mu$ in total variation distance as $t\to\infty$?

Comment: Not sure if the existence of a Foster-Lyapunov function implies (9).  The easiest and most quantitative approach is via couplings, which on unbounded spaces rely on Foster-Lyapunov functions or something comparable to confine most of the Langevin dynamics to a compact set.  You can read more about this here:  https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.1233

Comment: Thank you, I will check that out.

Comment: While working on that problem, I've encountered a question related to Fokker-Planck equations. I could imagine that you can answer it. Maybe you can take a look: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3079949/fokker-planck-equation-for-a-markov-semigroup-with-densities. Thank you in advance for your effort.